# Spring batch dynamic IN Query

Tags: spring, spring-batch

The following ItemReader get a list of thousands accounts that need to be retrieved from MD database.

In this approach I am limited to the number of accounts that I can use:

```
@StepScope
@Bean
public ItemReader<OmsDto> itemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[accOms]}") List<String> notLoadedFiles) {

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    notLoadedFiles.forEach(accountNumber -> buffer.append("'"+accountNumber+"',"));
    buffer.replace(buffer.length()- 1, buffer.length(), "");
    
    DriverManagerDataSource mdDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    mdDataSource.setDriverClassName("prestosql");
    mdDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:presto:....");
    mdDataSource.setUsername(".....");
    mdDataSource.setPassword("....");

    String sql ="SELECT DISTINCT "
             .....
             .....
            + "FROM MD.ONLINE WHERE acct IN ";
    JdbcCursorItemReader<OmsDto> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<OmsDto>();
    
    reader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
    reader.setDataSource(mdDataSource);
    reader.setSql(sql);
    reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
    BeanPropertyRowMapper<OmsDto> rowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(OmsDto.class);
    rowMapper.setPrimitivesDefaultedForNullValue(true);
    reader.setRowMapper(rowMapper);
    return reader;
}
```

What is the correct way to create dynamic IN Query (WHERE A IN (…, .., …)) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to generate IN query dynamically,

Example Query: SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID IN (?,?,?,?,?)

```
 List ids = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
    
 String inParams = String.join(",", ids.stream().map(id -> "?").collect(Collectors.toList()));


String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID IN (%s)", inParams);
```

Note that, if your query IN clause parameters limit more than 1000, it's better to use TEMP tables. Here some examples on [github](https://github.com/javabydeveloper/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-jdbc-example/src/test/java/com/javabydeveloper/demo/template/inClause/JdbcTemplateInClauseTest.java)

Comment: Thank you very much